# Toolbar like in the chrome app

Tags: android, toolbar

How can i get a toolbar that hides/shows when scrolling a webview down/up, that is also able to refresh by scrolling the listview up when the webview is at the top already (pulldownrefresh), just like the google chrome app for android .

Comment: check out the [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) app.

Answer (score 0):

For collapsing toolbar you will have to use the [CollapsingToolbarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) as explained in the [android design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) that has the collapsing toolbar.

And for pull down to refresh take a look at [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [this](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling(part1)/) wonderfull tutorial that explains it in a better way.

And for api details you can refer to [this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)

And for SwipeRefreshLayout you can check [this.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html)

These features are not so hard to implement.

I hope it would help you.

Comment: Thank you will certainly check it out :)